# How to organize the nautilus bookmarks in the "Places" panel applet?

Tags: nautilus, places, bookmarks

There seems to be no configuration dialog for the **Places** menu in the panel.
Yes, I know how to add, remove or change the order of the bookmarks in nautilus.

But I want to use folders and subfolders for the bookmarks. 
With more than 20 entries the nautilus bookmarks and the places menu become inconvenient.

- any editor for this?
- any configuration file that does the job?
- any other tool than the standard places menue?
- any extension for nautilus to extend the bookmark organization?

Comment: As far as I know there's only the drag/drop method. Or you could go to your .gtk-bookmarks folder in your home directory and add or remove more quickly.

Comment: Can I use subfolders within this .gtk-bookmark folder? I'd like to try but I can't find it using ubuntu maverick ... Could you give me the exact path? thx anyway, p.

Comment: Hit ctrl+h it's a hidden folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial request is from 2006?! o_O
https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/35347

Let's hope ... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, Places/Nautilus Bookmarks don't allow for sub-folders. While it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but since you ask for other tools [file-browser-applet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/file-browser-applet) [image: Install file-browser-applet] might be useful for you. It allows you to browse through folders from the GNOME panel.

[image]

Comment: thx andewsomething! I installed this applet but it's the same problem. I just want to have a kind of bookmarks organizer. I'm doing web development - meaning I have many FTP and network folders, many project folders, data sources, template folders for different purposes and stuff ... Using this applet shows my home folder with all subfolders (about 120).

Comment: Sure I could organize my home folder structure in the way I like to organize my bookmarks. But that's not the idea of bookmarks. It's nice to have a growing and evolving filesystem and orgnaize the view and access to it by bookmarks, folder labels or other means. So: Is there really no solution for nautlilus to have any kind of hierarchical bookmark organizing?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the philosophy behind **nautilus places** is that it should be kept flat, simple and short

Comment: You are right: The idea behind nautilus places is that it should be kept simple and short. That's why I'm asking. Please check back with the original post. BTW: The idea behind a computer is that it should do what users need it to do. And: the idea behind asking a question often is hoping to find a solution beyond the obvious.